# dataframe to dict in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
id    value
0     10.2
1      5.7
2      7.4
```

With `id` being the index. I want to have such output:

`{'0': 10.2, '1': 5.7, '2': 7.4}`

How to do this in python?

Comment: use `df.to_dict()`

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Use `to_dict` on the column:

```
>>> df['value'].to_dict()
{0: 10.2, 1: 5.7, 2: 7.4}
```

If you need the keys as strings:

```
>>> df.set_index(df.index.astype(str))['value'].to_dict()
{'0': 10.2, '1': 5.7, '2': 7.4}
```